# how to add tab to preference page as part of plugin development

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I have created a plugin showing in preference page of eclipse (using plugin develepment env of eclipse). I want to add tabs to this page but not able to find how to do so. 
i want tabs as circled in image

[image: i want tabs as circled]

Answer (score 1):

These tabs are just ordinary `TabFolder` (or `CTabFolder`) tabs. There is no special support for this in preference pages you just code the `TabFolder` and `TabItem`s in the `createContents` method of the preference page.

Your example page is created by `org.eclipse.compare.internal.ComparePreferencePage`, you could look at the source of that.